# Tikz complex flowchart with custom shapes

Tags: tikz-pgf, flow-charts, pdflscape, tikzpagenodes

I'm trying to recreate the "flowchart" below using Tikz. I was able to create the various shapes., but I've run into several problems:

1. The page should be displayed in landscape, but the package `pdflscape` destroys the whole figure.
2. Each element should be equally spaced, i.e. like a grid.
3. I can't figure out how to keep it easily adjustable, like controlling the size of all rectangles at once and the `circle` size in the "`spe`" `node`.
4. Another important thing is the arrow connections. I would like the angles instead of a straight line.
5. How can I place the four circles on the border, so that when I adjust it they automatically follow it?

[image]

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass[headinclude]{scrbook}
\usepackage[left=32.5mm, right=25mm, top=25mm, bottom=20mm, showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[font={small}]{caption}
\usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{calc}
    \usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
    \tikzset{>=stealth}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usepackage{pdflscape}

\begin{document}

% \begin{landscape}
\begin{figure}
    \newcommand{\zustand}[1]{%
        \begin{scope}[rotate=90, transform shape]
            \node[circle, draw, fill=white, minimum size=0.7cm, above, label={[align=center, fill=white]above:{#1}}] at (1,1) {};
        \end{scope}%
    }
    \centering\small
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
        \draw[ultra thick] ($(current page text area.north west)+(0.8pt,-1cm)$) rectangle ($(current page text area.south east) + (-0.8pt,1cm) $);
        \zustand{test\\test long};

        \node[rectangle, draw, minimum width=1.5cm, minimum height=0.75cm, rotate=90] (lei) {};
        \draw (lei.west) -- (lei.east);

        \node[rectangle, draw, minimum width=1.5cm, minimum height=0.75cm, rotate=90] (wan) at (2,14) {};
        \draw (wan.north west) -- (wan.east) -- (wan.south west);

        \node[rectangle, draw, minimum width=1.5cm, minimum height=0.75cm, rotate=90] (spe) at (2,2) {};
        \draw (spe.center) circle (0.375cm);

        \node[rectangle, draw, minimum width=1.5cm, minimum height=0.75cm, rotate=90] (ver) at (1,1) {};
        \draw (ver.north west) -- (ver.center) -- (ver.south west);
        \draw (ver.center) -- (ver.east);

        \draw[->, dotted] (ver.east) -- (wan.west);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Test}
\end{figure}
% \end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

Comment: If you want automatic equal spacing between nodes, you should use the `chains` or `positioning` libraries of Ti*k*Z. Lanscape or portrait should be something handled after creating the figure for me : create your picture with the `standalone` class, then incliude it as a graphic image. Regarding sizes, even if you provide paths with a pre-defined style, you still can add other options locally. I am not sure what you call the border, but you can place nodes on paths as you want. These are just my remarks ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not an answer but some comments that I hope can help OP to easily draw his scheme.

First of all, I've defined some `.styles` to draw every different element. All of them are based on a `basic` node which fixes dimensions while particular styles just define the inner `path picture`. This solves question 3.

Nodes positioning is solved with `positioning library` (question 2). The picture has a default `node distance` to save some typing, but this can be particularly changed in every new node. This distance can be also used within a `chain` as BambOo suggest in a previous comment. Another solution if nodes distribution was more regular could be a `matrix`.

Following example shows cornered connections (question 4) but I'm not sure if this it want this question means.

And about fifth question, I think that one all scheme is drawn,  a border line can be easily defined. And this is better than trying to adjust the drawing to a fixed border.

```
\documentclass[headinclude]{scrbook}
\usepackage[left=32.5mm, right=25mm, top=25mm, bottom=20mm, showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[font={small}]{caption}
\usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{calc, positioning, fit, backgrounds}
    \usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
    \tikzset{>=stealth}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usepackage{pdflscape}

\tikzset{
    zustand/.style={circle, draw, fill=white, minimum size=0.7cm,
        label={[align=center, fill=white]{#1}}},
    basic/.style={rectangle, draw, minimum width=1.5cm, minimum height=0.75cm},
    lei/.style={basic,
        path picture={\draw (path picture bounding box.west)--(path picture bounding box.east);}},
    wan/.style={basic,
        path picture={\draw (path picture bounding box.north west)--(path picture bounding box.east)--(path picture bounding box.south west);}},
    ver/.style={basic,
        path picture={\draw (path picture bounding box.north west)--(path picture bounding box.center)--(path picture bounding box.south west); \draw(path picture bounding box.center)--(path picture bounding box.east);}},
    spe/.style={basic,
        path picture={\draw (path picture bounding box.center) let \p1=($ (path picture bounding box.north)-(path picture bounding box.south)$) in circle({veclen(\x1,\y1)/2});}},
}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering\small
    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 1cm and 2cm,
        line/.style={->, dotted}]
        \node[zustand={test\\test long}] (zustand-a) {};

        \node[lei, right=of zustand-a] (lei-a) {};

        \node[wan, above right=of lei-a] (wan-a) {};

        \node[spe, below=of wan-a] (spe-a) {};

        \node[ver, below left=of spe-a] (ver-a) {};

        \node[zustand={test\\test long}, left=of ver-a.south west] (zustand-b) {};

        \node[zustand={test\\test long}, right=of wan-a] (zustand-c) {};


        \draw[line] (zustand-a) -- (lei-a);
        \draw[line] (lei-a.east) -- ++(0:5mm)|-(wan-a);
        \draw[line] (wan-a.east) --++(5mm,0)|- (spe-a);
        \draw[line] (spe-a.south west)--++(180:5mm)|-(ver-a.south east);
        \draw[line] (ver-a.south west)--(zustand-b);

        \draw[line, thick] (spe-a.south east)-|++(1,-0.5)-|([xshift=-5mm]ver-a.north west)--(ver-a.north west);

        \begin{scope}[on background layer]
        \node[fit={([yshift=-5mm]zustand-b.south) ([yshift=3cm]zustand-c.north)}, inner sep=0pt, draw, thick] {};
        \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Test}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm still struggling with two things: the longest connection with five edges and positioning with `above=of` etc. Having so many dependencies makes it hard to adjust later.

Comment: @Johannes I've edited the answer with a five edges connection and a border. I don't understand your concerns about positioning. If you previously plan your figure it's easy to adjust everything with positioning library. You don't need to use `above=of` or `right=of` with all nodes, you can also use `at (spe-a-|ver-b)` or `shifts` or any other solution for particular  nodes.